# You are charged on the basis of new payment or you are billed a new payment? What is correct?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I am not a native speaker but this question worries me a lot. There is an email where is indicated the total number you are to pay and this payment is new. So the question is, what phrase should I write:

> "You are charged on the basis of new payment"

or

> "You are billed a new payment"?

What variant is correct or are both not OK? Would be a pleasure to hear your options.

Comment: Neither of these make any sense at all, unfortunately. "Charging" and "billing" refer to the company requesting money; "payment" is the customer sending the money. "Charged on the basis of new payment" seems backwards; what exactly are you trying to say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the key word you are looking for is "new bill" or more formally: "new invoice"

In full, I would expect something like:

"You have a new bill for £123.99 which is now due."